# Mirror modifier - the mirrored half is darker

Tags: materials, normals, mirror

I am working on a complex project with different 3D models I downloaded from the internet.

I have to mirror many of them relative to the global x axis (I used a plane as mirror object), but as you can see the mirrored half is darker both in solid and rendered view. The material is the same, the lighting is uniform, the normals seem to be correct and there aren't double vertices.

[image]

Also, I would very prefer to not apply the modifier

---

Here there is a simple .blend with one of the objects that give me this problem:

[image]

Comment: there's a surface between the two, are you sure it's not your problem?

Comment: the plane is needed to tell blender what the center of the mirror is.
In any case, I tried the same setup with a simple cube and it works, even with the plane in the middle

Comment: I remove and add mirror modifier with default setup - and it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: the issue was caused by the plane's rotation.

It seems like the **Mirror Modifier** doesn't work when the mirror object is rotated, so I needed to apply the rotation of the plane to make it work

Comment: Hello :). Please mark your answer as accepted, to keep the site nice and tidy :). Thanks.

Comment: @JachymMichal sorry, I was a new user back then, I didn't know about this stuff ahah